# How do i stop this while loop in python

Tags: python

How do I stop this `while` loop?

```
Sentence = input("Please enter the sentence: ").lower()

if "." in Sentence or "'" in Sentence or "," in Sentence or ";" in Sentence or ":" in Sentence or "/" in Sentence or "?" in Sentence or "!" in Sentence or "-" in Sentence:  
    while Sentence:
        print("Your sentence is invalid. Please enter the sentence without punctuation") 
else:
    allWords = Sentence.split()

    print(allWords)

    FindWord = input("Enter the word you are looking for: ").lower()
    for L in range(len(allWords)):
        if FindWord == allWords[L]:
            print("The word <", FindWord, "> is found in", L,"th positions")
```

Comment: Please read documentation on How ask a good question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Use the `break` keyword to break out of the loop when your condition is satisfied. Written a bit shorter, you can do something like

```
while True:
    Sentence = input("Please enter the sentence: ").lower()
    if any(c in Sentence for c in ".',;:/?!-"):
        print("Your sentence is invalid. Please enter the sentence without punctuation")
    else:
        # Accept input
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `Sentence` to falsy value `(False, '', 0)` if you aren't going to re-use it.

Answer (score -2):

```
Sentence=input("Please enter the sentence: ").lower()

while "." in Sentence or "'" in Sentence or "," in Sentence or ";" in Sentence or ":" in Sentence or "/" in Sentence or "?" in Sentence or "!" in Sentence or "-" in Sentence::    
    print("Your sentence is invalid. Please enter the sentence without punctuation") 
    Sentence=input("Please enter the sentence: ").lower()
```

Use the conditional to check whether to keep looping.  and put a way to change `Sentence` in the loop